# Hangfire - access server from job?

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

I am using hangfire to distribute jobs to several servers (which live on separate machines).

Sometimes a job fails, because the machine/server that processes it on is not in a ready state (e.g., an application the job uses has crashed, etc.). Now I'd like to shut down the server programmatically so that it does not accept more jobs and can be repaired. How can I do that, as all the code runs in a job class that does not know of the server, and all the server code does is host a hangfireserver instance?

More specifically, my server application looks as follows:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HangFireDBConnection");

        var serverOptions = new BackgroundJobServerOptions {
            WorkerCount = 1
        };

        using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer(serverOptions)) {

            ConsoleHelpers.ConfigureConsole();
            ConsoleHelpers.WriteWelcomeMessage();

            char userInput = '\0';
            while (userInput != 'q') {
                if (userInput == 'l') {
                    ConsoleHelpers.WriteLogFileToConsole();
                }
                userInput = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It just hosts the server and shows some information based on user input.

Comment: You are talking about either pushing `server` to a global scope, or inject it within every job? Why not use an IOC (http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-ioc-containers.html), register the `BackgroundJobServer` with that container and resolve all jobs from there (either via ctor-injection or service locator pattern)? see http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/passing-dependencies.html

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, I don't really understand your proposal. The jobs are created and enqueued in a totally different application (a web API) and my servers are console applications running on different machines. Hangfire then processes jobs in the background, but in a job class I don't have a reference to a server - in fact they don't even know of servers at all, not even of Hangfire...

Comment: So you are not talking about `server` as your _server_, but rather the physical entity?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Well, both, sorry for the confusion: I mean I'd like to (shut down/take out of the loop) the hangfire-server whenever the physical server is in an unhelathy state. My hangfire jobs start other applications on the physical server, and when the job fails because the apps crashed, I need an admin to fix the physical server. It should not accept jobs anymore, hence the job should deactivate the hangfire-server it is currently processed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way I was able to solve this problem: In the class defining the Job, I can define a static property. This can be of any type - let me give a string example here:

```
namespace MyJobProject {
   public class MyJob() {
       public static string message {get; private set;} = "Hello!";
       // other code in the job class
   }
}
```

Then in the server code I can access that property since it is static, i.e., in the `while` loop in the original question I can write

```
while (userInput != 'q') {
    if (userInput == 'l') {
        ConsoleHelpers.WriteLogFileToConsole();
    }
    userInput = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    Console.Writeline(MyJob.Message);
}
```

Remember to reference the namespace `MyJobProject` though - although that is already necessary for the jobs to work at all.